# Find invoices that include a specific charge

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently analyzing a set of invoices that are equal to zero or some charges that may be duplicated.

The invoices equal to zero could be resolved through the following query:

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber, ACCUNT_NUM,  
    SUM(Amount) AS Amount 
FROM Invoice 
GROUP BY InvoiceNumber, ACCUNT_NUM 
HAVING SUM(Amount) = 0
```

However, in the analysis I have obtained cases that I want to include within my scope, for example "invoices that have a specific charge such as" Deliquency Cost "and the rest of the charges are equal to zero.

I put an example in the Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6d876/4

For example I want to list when a case like invoice 999, included in the previous link.

Comment: use a where statement, SELECT InvoiceNumber, ACCUNT_NUM,  
     SUM(Amount) AS Amount 
FROM Invoice  where servicio = 'Extra charge'

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6d876/2/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want cases where all the charges are for `Servicio = 'Deliquency Cost'`:

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber, ACCUNT_NUM,  
       SUM(Amount) AS Amount 
FROM Invoice 
GROUP BY InvoiceNumber, ACCUNT_NUM 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Servicio = 'Deliquency Cost' THEN Amount END) = SUM(Amount);
```

This assumes there are no negative charges.

Or to just get invoices that have the charge:

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber, ACCUNT_NUM,  
       SUM(Amount) AS Amount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Servicio = 'Deliquency Cost' THEN Amount END) as delinquency_cost
FROM Invoice 
GROUP BY InvoiceNumber, ACCUNT_NUM 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Servicio = 'Deliquency Cost' THEN Amount END) > -
```

You might want:

```
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Servicio <> 'Deliquency Cost' THEN Amount END) = 0
```

Which says that everything else adds up to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get these cases with extra conditions in the HAVING clause:

```
SELECT 
  InvoiceNumber, ACCUNT_NUM,  
  SUM(Amount) AS Amount 
FROM Invoice 
GROUP BY InvoiceNumber, ACCUNT_NUM 
HAVING 
  SUM(CASE WHEN Servicio = 'Deliquency Cost' THEN 1 END) > 0
  AND
  SUM(CASE WHEN Servicio <> 'Deliquency Cost' THEN Amount END) = 0
```

This returns:

> invoices that have a specific charge such as" Deliquency Cost "and the
>   rest of the charges are equal to zero